# Console closing prematurely. EDIT: Sum and Average not computing correctly

Tags: c++, c++11

This code works well as long as I write an invalid input. The error message prints, and you just have to close the console and start over. But, can I have the program start again from the beginning with the console open? Also, the big failure, and prime question, is that when a valid input is entered, the console just closes. I have no idea why, and I'm new to C++, so please bear with me. :)

EDIT: Now that @merlin2011 was so kind as to point out my super simple mistake, the program is doing much better! Thanks a million! But, the new problem on the street is that my calculations aren't working correctly. I printed my sum to see if it's correct, and I think because I have int letters = 0;, it counts the sum as 0. I think I need to change this to a reference integer? So int& letters =0;, but how can I have it store it's new value later??

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Prototype to keep console from closing.
class KeepRunning {
  public:
    ~KeepRunning() {
      cin.get();}};

//Define batting values
#define H  1
#define h  1
#define O  1
#define o  1
#define W  0
#define w  0
#define S  0
#define s  0
#define P  0
#define p  0

int main ()
{
    KeepRunning kr;

    int player;                 //Assign player number
    double sum;                 //Assign variable for sum of H, h and O, o
    double sumHits;             //Assign variable for sum of only H and h
    double average;             //Assign variable for average of H and O
    char size[100];             //Allows compiler to view user input as array
    int b=0;                    //Assign variable for integer size
    int letters = 0;            //Assing value of 0 to allow compiler to count

    cout << "\t\t\tBatting Average Calculator\t\t";

    do
    {
         cout << "\n\nEnter the player's number: ";
         cin >> player;

         cout << "Enter the player's batting record: ";
         cin >> size;

         if (size[b] != 'H' && size[b] != 'h' &&
             size[b] != 'O' && size[b] != 'o' &&
             size[b] != 'W' && size[b] != 'w' &&
             size[b] != 'S' && size[b] != 's' &&
             size[b] != 'P' && size[b] != 'p' || cin.fail()) 
          {
            cout << "\nAcceptable batting record codes are: 'H','O','W','S','P'.Please try again.\n";
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(); 
          }            
    } while (size[b] != 'H' && size[b] != 'h' &&
             size[b] != 'O' && size[b] != 'o' &&
             size[b] != 'W' && size[b] != 'w' &&
             size[b] != 'S' && size[b] != 's' &&
             size[b] != 'P' && size[b] != 'p' || cin.fail()); 
             return 0;  

    //Summate H, h, O, o
    sum = letters;

    //Summate 
    sumHits = H + h;

    //Calculate batting average
    average = sumHits/sum;

    cout << "\nPlayer " << player << "'s batting record: " << size << endl;
    cout << "Player " << player << "'s batting average: " << average << endl;

    std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue...";
    std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );    
}
```

Comment: Anything below the line `return 0;` will not execute.

Comment: Well, that's stupid of me. Ha.

Answer (score 0):

Where to start...

1. As @merlin2011 said, anything below the line `return 0;' will not execute.
2. User input is not really used (except for the validation). I have no idea of what you are trying to do, but I'd say that `size` contents should have some influence in `sumHits`.
3. `letters` is not increased anywhere. Its definition is fine (don't touch it!)... just needs to increase it for each item in the average.
4. `b` is not increased anywhere. I could guess that your input is a string of letters, each of them meaning something... so you're probably missing a loop on b that goes over the string of letters, increasing `letters` and adding values to `sumHits` according to the different letters entered by the user.

btw, [using `#define` for constants is considered bad practice in C++...](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/const-vs-define.html)

modified code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits> // added because of the numeric limits at the end
#include <cstring> // added because of strlen
using namespace std;

//Prototype to keep console from closing.
//This is probably not needed anymore
class KeepRunning {
  public:
    ~KeepRunning() {
      cin.get();}};


int main ()
{
    KeepRunning kr; // not sure if this is needed

    int player;                 //Assign player number
    double sumHits;             //Assign variable for sum of only H and h
    double average;             //Assign variable for average of H and O
    char size[100];             //Allows compiler to view user input as array
    int b=0;                    //Assign variable for integer size
    int letters = 0;            //Assing value of 0 to allow compiler to count

    // probably the above variables can be moved inside the loop.

    cout << "\t\t\tBatting Average Calculator\t\t";

    do
    {
         cout << "\n\nEnter the player's number: ";
         cin >> player;

         cout << "Enter the player's batting record: ";
         cin >> size;

         // Now size should probably be a std::string... 
         // Now we have an input, loop through it
         // initialize variables
         letters = 0;
         sumHits = 0.0;
         for(b=0;b<strlen(size);b++) {
              // Now check each letter
              switch(size[b]) {
              case 'H': // fallthrough
              case 'h':
                 sumHits+=1;
                 letters++;
                 break;
              case 'O': // fallthrough
              case 'o':
                 letters++;
                 break;
              case 'S': // fallthrough
              case 's': // fallthrough
              case 'P': // fallthrough
              case 'p': // fallthrough
                 // not sure what these are... so just skip
                 break;
              default:
                 // syntax error
                 cout << "\nAcceptable batting record codes are: 'H','O','W','S','P'.Please try again.\n";
                 cin.clear();
                 cin.ignore();
                 letters=0; // reset the count so that we don't process the average
              }
          }
          if(letters==0) {
              // we didn't get a valid input, start the loop again
              continue;
          }
          //Calculate batting average
          average = sumHits/letters;

          cout << "\nPlayer " << player << "'s batting record: " << size << endl;
          cout << "Player " << player << "'s batting average: " << average << endl;

          std::cout << "Press ENTER to continue...";
          std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
     }
     while(!cin.fail()); // repeat until the standard input ends.
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I moved my return statement which is why I was able to move on to the edited question. 

I tried to set sum equal to size, but I couldn't because it said I was trying to convert type char to double, I tried implementing something else :/. How can I use size without disturbing the compiler??

Comment: Yeah, the input has to be a series of the defined letters lol. Can I use an enumerator instead of #define??? I am really new to this, so I'm sorry for the "dumb" questions.

Comment: @whatsHerFace The thing is that I don't reall understand what you're trying to do.... If each letter in size[] array means something, then you probably need to loop through the array, check each letter (a switch-case maybe?) and increase the sumHits and index accordingly. As for what to use instead of defines: whatever is more convenient for you, check the FAQ link I posted.... but there can be other options that could help you better in mapping from a letter to its meaning.

Comment: I changed all the definitions to const chars, and I'm trying to write a program that calculates a players batting average. So the only characters that have a value should be H,h (hits) and O,o (outs). Sum is supposed to find this. sumHits is supposed to summate only hits. Average is hits/hits and outs combined.

Comment: @whatsHerFace read my comments... Excuse me, but I'm not going to write more. This looks like a homework assignment to me. Providing you with working code will not help you learning. There's no magic in programming, just putting out in code the detailed process that the program must follow. So just write down in words (pseudo-code) what you need to do and that might help you in translating it into c++ code

Comment: Thanks for your help. It is a homework assignment. It's an online class, and I learn by seeing. The instructor provides powerpoints which mirror the text. So when I don't understand the text, SEEING code that works IS how I learn. I appreciate the help, although now I'm even more confused. I'm trying to write a switch case code like you suggested, but it's not working. Psuedo-code wise, the program needs to read the string input by the user and determine whether it's valid. It does. If it's wrong, it outputs the error message and begins again.

Comment: However, it is correct, it goes on to sum, then sumHits, then average. The issue I'm working on right now is the fact that sum does not work properly. Rather than sum being set equal to letters (Which is set equal to 0 at the getgo), the program needs to read the string input by the user (a combo of the letters H,O,W,S,P, where H=1, O=1, and the rest are equal to zero), and sum THOSE characters.  I tried to use an enumerator at the beginning of the code because it seemed like a good idea, but I couldn't make it work so I tried to go back to the basics.

Comment: Not to mention this array is defined as characters instead of numbers, which kind of blows my mind a little bit.

Comment: @whatsHerFace code provided. Tried to add comments explaining what's going on.

Comment: Okay, that helped a lot. Now I can see that the reason my switch case wasn't working earlier is because I can list all cases before I tell the program what to do. I had a case, then a direction, a case, then a direction, etc. This was giving an error that said the direction had already been given.

Comment: The problem with a switch statement is that the break; causes the count to start over. So the break after counting hits sets letters back to 0, then the average is calculated with just outs divided by all

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks!